# Java - Math.ceil rounds 1.0 up to 2.0

Tags: java, java-8

I'm finishing an implementation of a hash map built in Java, and am using quadratic probing to handle collisions.  To do this, I am using a helper method which will return the next offset to be added to the initial hash/table index.

I've stepped through the test with Eclipse's debugger, and found that when I pass in `2`, I get out `-4`, even though I should get `-1`. This happens when `Math.ceil` is called on `probeCount`, which equals `1.0` at the time of calling. `Math.ceil` transforms probeCount from `1.0` to `2.0`, which causes an incorrect return value.

Would someone help me correct the code, and explain what I'm doing wrong?

This is the helper method:

```
protected int nextBucketIndex (int probeCount) {

    if (probeCount == 0)
        return 0;

    if (probeCount % 2 == 0) {

        double n = (double) probeCount / 2.0;

        n = Math.ceil(probeCount); // <-----Line that produces the error.

        n = Math.pow(n, 2);

        n *= -1;

        return (int) n;
    } else {

        double n = probeCount / 2.0;

        n = Math.ceil(probeCount);

        n = Math.pow(n, 2);

        return (int) n;         
    }
}
```

Here is the test case I am using to test the method:

```
@Test
public void nextBucketIndexShouldOperateByPattern() { // 1^2, -1^2, 2^2, -2^2, 3^2, etc.

    HashCollection<Integer> table = new HashCollection<Integer>();

    assertEquals (0, table.nextBucketIndex(0));
    assertEquals (1, table.nextBucketIndex(1));
    assertEquals (-1, table.nextBucketIndex(2));
    assertEquals (4, table.nextBucketIndex(3));
    assertEquals (-4, table.nextBucketIndex(4));
    assertEquals (9, table.nextBucketIndex(5));
    assertEquals (-9, table.nextBucketIndex(6));
    assertEquals (16, table.nextBucketIndex(7));
    assertEquals (-16, table.nextBucketIndex(8));

}
```

Comment: Floating point numbers do funny things. It's probably 1.00000003 or something silly, so it gets rounded up. There's technical reasons, I just haven't tried to learn them yet.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `n = Math.ceil(n);`?

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, that was exactly the problem.  Whoops.  Thanks for being a second pair of eyes.  You answered first, so if you post an answer, I'll go ahead and mark it. :)

Comment: Just mark Durandal's answer, it's correct and offers additional info, so good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculate **n / 2.0**, but you feed probeCount to Math.ceil(). That should have been n.

But instead, I'd simply use integer math and a bit of bitshifting:

```
public static int nextBucketIndex(int n) {
    int h = n >> 1;
    h *= h;
    return (n & 1) == 0 ? h : -h; 
}
```

Division by 2 is a simple shift by one to the right. Since your power is always two, simply multiply the number by itself. Even/odd is easily tested by and'ing with 1.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I have to admit, I'm not advanced enough in Java to understand all of the concepts behind that syntax, but I'm grateful to see it in front of me.  I'll be interested to learn about that stuff in the future. :)

Comment: @Tyme96: In case, you’re not understanding the bit operators, note that even when using `/ 2` and `% 2`, Java usually is smart enough to replace it with the faster operators internally. The key point here is to use `int` consistently, as there is no need for `double` operations. Since all operators besides `pow` exist for `int` and `double` equally, you only have to understand that `a² == a*a`, which is basic arithmetic, so you don’t need to use `Math.pow(…,2)`.